# Align a table, center(the td) and left the text inside td

Tags: css

I am trying to align a table, center(the td) and left the text inside td;

I try to use **flex** to align center, which in a way it does, but can't align left.

I've seen the solution which uses `padding-left: 50%`, but that doesn't fit my needs.

```css
table {
    color: #212121;
    font-size: .875rem;
    margin: 1.25rem 0; 
    border-collapse: collapse;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid red;
}


tr {
    display:flex;   
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: center;
}

tr td { 
    max-width: 50%;
    text-align:left;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>lorem ipsum</td>
      <td>alpha</td>
     </tr> 
     <tr>
      <td>lorem ipsum ipsum</td>
      <td>teata ipsum alpha</td>
     </tr>                
   </tbody>
</table>
```

What I want to obtain:

The border line, are just for distance comparison

[image]

Comment: Are you expecting output like this https://jsfiddle.net/78h1Lv02/1/ ?

Comment: or like this https://jsfiddle.net/78h1Lv02/2/ ??

Comment: no, I updated with an image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can insert span tag in table,html code:

```
 <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><span>lorem ipsum</span></td>
          <td><span>alpha</span></td>
         </tr> 
         <tr>
          <td><span>lorem ipsum ipsum</span></td>
          <td><span>teata ipsum alpha
            teata ipsum alpha</span></td>
         </tr>                
       </tbody>
    </table>
```

css code:

```
table {
    color: #212121;
    font-size: .875rem;
    margin: 1.25rem 0; 
    border-collapse: collapse;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid red;
}


tr {
    display:flex;   
    justify-content: center;
    text-align:center;

}
tr td{
    border: 1px solid blue;
    width:50%;

}
tr td span{ 
   display:inline-block; 
   width:50%;  
   text-align:left; 
    white-space:break;
}
```

this result's link:
https://jsbin.com/huvitefeqe/edit?html,css,js,output

Answer (score 0):

**[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/78h1Lv02/3/)**

```
tr {
    display:flex;   
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    justify-content: center;
}

tr td { 
   max-width: 50%;
   text-align:left;
   border: 1px solid blue;
   width: 100%
}
```

Add `width: 50%; margin: 0 auto;` to `tr` and add `width: 100%` to `tr td`. I hope you are expecting output like this.

You can see td is center of the table and text also aligned left of the td.

Comment: no, I updated with an image to be more clear, the border line, are just for distance comparisson

Answer (score 0):

Border spacing kinda solves this.

```css
table {
    color: #212121;
    font-size: 0.875rem;
    margin: 1.25rem 0;
    border-collapse: separate;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid red;
    border-spacing: 5px 0;
}

td {
  padding: 10px 10px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>lorem ipsum</td>
      <td>alpha</td>
     </tr> 
     <tr>
      <td>lorem ipsum ipsum</td>
      <td>teata ipsum alpha</td>
     </tr>                
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: the content doesn't have a fixed width to use predefined padding and the proposed solution is not centered